# Issue connecting to LDAP through PHP

Tags: php, ldap

My company recently changed domains due to an ownership change and I am having an issue getting my LDAP bind to complete on the new domain.

My connect command creates the resource correctly but when I go to bind I get the error.

> "Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Strong(er) authentication required"

I am not using ldaps.  I have confirmed I have the correct domain url for LDAP.

`$ad` is the resource, `$dmun` is the username with domain added and the `$pw` is the password.

```
$bd = ldap_bind($ad,$dmun,$pw);
```

It's an intranet site.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code. This code worked for me

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$ldap_host = "domain.com";
$ldap_port = 389;
$base_dn = "DC=domain,DC=com";
$filter = '(sAMAccountName=' . $username . ')';
$connect = ldap_connect($ldap_host, $ldap_port) or exit("Error : Could not connect to LDAP server.");
if ($connect) {
    ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    if (@$bind = ldap_bind($connect, "$username@domain.com", $password)) {
        echo "Bind Successfull";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Username / Password";
    }
}
```

Comment: Results in the same as my original error.  Strong(er) auth required

Comment: Did you used ssl port??

Comment: AD DS isn't using SSL I have checked with my AD team.